# how can I send the comple yaml file with a rest request in springboot?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, yaml, swagger

I have a yaml file which is a swagger and with http://editor.swagger.io/ I have generated a spring project.

The I want to send the complete yaml file with a request.

As it only send json with a response, how could I send the yaml?

Thanks

Comment: yaml is string with specific formatting, you can send as string.

Comment: What do you mean by "complete YAML file" and where do you want to send it? Please add more details.